# Unpack tensorflow Tensor columns into separate variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Given a tensor of the form

```
T = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
```

How can I separate T into two separate tensors of shape (?, 1), one for each column?

Answer (score 2):

You can slice out tensors using python's *slice notation*.

```
x = T[:, 0, None]
y = T[:, 1, None]
```

Internally, this delegates to `Tensor.__getitem__`, and is evaluated as part of the graph.